# Determine the origin of a keystroke message

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, hook, sendinput

I'm sending/simulating mousekeystrokes via SendInput and monitoring this key with a LLHook.
Of course the messages by SendInput get logged by the Hook - but now i'm trying to to determine inside the HookProc if the message comes from Sendinput or from the real mouse. Is this possible?

Comment: No. This isn't possible. `SendInput` writes into the same buffer as hardware device drivers.

Comment: Raymond Chen even shows a nice diagram of that on his blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/02/13/10499047.aspx "*When you call Send­Input, you're putting input packets into the system hardware input queue*"